# Class without parameterless constructor C++

Tags: c++

I have a class in my program which is a file parser to provide me with outputs. Since this is a file parse, passing a filename is mandatory to use this class.

**FileReader.h**

```
class FileReader{
public:
FileReader(std::string filePath);
//other member functions
private:
//private variables
};
```

**MainProgram.h**

```
class MainProgram{
public:
FileReader reader; //this gives error
private:
};
```

**MainProgram.cpp**

```
MainProgram::setup()
{
public:
    reader = new FileReader("files/something.xml") //intended to use like this
}
```

**Error:** src/MainProgram.h|57|error: no matching function for call to ‘FileReader::FileReader()’|

How do I keep the class with a mandatory parameter during initialization?

Comment: Why not give `MainProgram` a constructor so it can properly initialize `FileReader`?

Comment: Initialization inside .h file is not permitted right? `MainProgram.h`

Comment: Why would initialization inside a header file be forbidden?

Comment: @user1240679, If you're against initializing it in the header, provide the constructor definition in the implementation. It's not an error to initialize something in a header, though.

Comment: If I try to initialize in the following format FileReader reader = new FileReader("files/file.xml");` in my MainProgram.h file, I get the following error: `src/MainProgram.h|106|error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member ‘reader’ [-fpermissive]|`

Comment: @user1240679, That's only inside of the class definition pre-C++11. It's perfectly fine to initialize it in a constructor contained in the header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace:

```
FileReader(std::string filePath)();  // not valid way of providing function definition
```

with:

```
FileReader(std::string filePath){}
```

also you need to initialize FileReader in MainProgram constructor `member initialzer list`.

If you want to use `new FileReader` in setup function, then reader needs to be a pointer type.

```
class MainProgram{
public:
  MainProgram(const std::string& file):reader(file){} // init reader in member initializer
private:
  FileReader reader; 
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  MainProgram test("files/something.xml");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: While that _is_ an error, fixing it would still result in the same error the OP sees

Comment: Not valid as in? In my `.h` files, I have many functions with the followinf format for eg: `void keyPressed  (int key);` and I then provide the full functionality in .cpp file, and these work fine. Is there something wrong in this?

Comment: @user1240679, That doesn't have `()` after it.

Comment: @chris: Ah! That was a typo in the post. Not in the program though

Comment: I am finding this kind of strange. In C#, I would have declared a class with something like `FileReader abcReader` and in my function would have done something like `abcReader = new FileReader('blah.xml');` Here in C++, I can't declare a class object if it doesn't have parameterless constructor or probably I am doing something wrong.

Comment: That means if I have to adopt a similar C# approach, I would only have the option to delcare it as a pointer something like `FileReader *abcReader`?

Comment: @user1240679, You can declare it fine, but the constructor is what initializes it. You can choose how through use of the member initializer list (`: FileReader("...")`), which is also somewhat present in C#. Since C++11, you can also do it right in the class body: `FileReader reader{"..."};` or, in this case, `FileReader reader = "...";`

Comment: @user1240679 you need to provide default constructor if you want to FileReader without parameter.

Comment: @user1240679 also `FileReader reader` is enough for you case, there is no need to introduce a pointer.

Comment: @billz: My project is openFramework ISO C++ project and `FileReader reader` in .h file somehow does not compile. That's why the question was here. Error: `no matching function for call to ‘FileReader::FileReader()’|

Comment: @user1240679  `MainProgram(const std::string& file):reader(file){}` initialize it in member initiazer list should fix your issue.

Comment: @user1240679, It should compile if you implement one of our answers (and the pointer ones as well, but I wouldn't suggest getting into memory leaks).

Comment: @billz: Does that mean everytime I have to declare such a class, I would have to use the `MainProgra(const std::string& file):reader(file){}` format declaration  format for all the declarations?

Comment: mostly yes, you want to initialize your members explicitly in good order etc. It's good practical coding style.

Comment: @user1240679, That's the accepted (and sometimes necessary) convention to initialize members of your class. You only need to do it for the members you don't need default-initialized.

Answer (score 2):

If that's your whole `setup` function, do away with it and use a constructor instead - that's what they're there for!

```
MainProgram::MainProgram() : reader("files/something.xml"){}
```

That *initializes* (as in calls its constructor) `reader` with the string provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileReader * reader; // This line should not create a FileReader object on stack, a pointer is enough
```

The syntax here of C++ is different from Java/C#. You need declare a explicit pointer type in the statement.

Comment: Why is this a preferred approach? I come from a C# background and wasn't sure about the way of initialization.

Comment: In C#, 'FileReader reader' is just a reference or pointer. But in C++, it will call ctor to create an object.

Comment: @user1240679, Read this for the preferred C++ approach: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C++.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try `FileReader *reader;` instead?